# Hec Ras Error Message

Tags: hec-ras

[image]

I am getting this error when I am running unsteady flow analysis.I run geometric correction mesh calculation but still, the error is same.

Comment: Please do not post images of error messages, or at least *only* images. Questions should contain the actual error message as ASCII text in the body of the question, so that 1) others may search for the same error, and 2) the error will be legible on all display devices. Failure to do this conveys the message, "I only care if I get my answer,  not if the question is of general use to the community," and generates downvotes in response.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your ERDAS was installed on a network drive that you lost connection to.

Try installing ERDAS locally and trying again.